# Inserting the contents of another page, using Lift

Tags: jquery, dom, lift

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to Lift.

Suppose I already have a URL on returning dynamically generated content, at e.g. `/data/???`. I'd now like to include this include inside a `div` on another page, based on user input. I would have thought I could use do this "by hand" using jQuery, e.g.

```
<input type="text" onchange="$('#dynamic').load('/data/' + this.value)"/>
<div id="dynamic"/>
```

and indeed this works **outside of Lift**. When I do this on a page served by Lift, however, the content doesn't load, and looking in the Javascript console I see an `INVALID_STATE_ERR`, DOM exception 11, being thrown from deep inside jQuery.

Two questions:

> 1) Why is this happening? Can I fix it and continue using jQuery's load function 'by hand' on a Lift generated page?
>
> 2) What is 'the Lift way' to dynamically update a `div`, based on content generated outside of Lift?

Comment: i never heard lift way  what is liftway ??

Comment: @gov, Lift http://liftweb.net/ is a web framework, written in Scala. By 'the Lift way' I meant whatever way people familiar with Lift think is best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery seems to be unhappy dealing with XHTML here. Make sure that the "outer" page is not delivered with an XHTML mimetype, e.g. `LiftRules.useXhtmlMimeType = false` and jQuery works again.